# Sympy - get scalar out of vector, reference frame module

Tags: python, sympy

I have a very simple code, with a simple problem. I can't find the answers and tried everything that seemed logic to me. Anyways I have the code:

```
import sympy as sp
from sympy.physics.vector import *
N = ReferenceFrame('N')
f = 1*N.x+2*N.y
```

So f should now be a vector storing the values (1,2). x and y being 1 and 2 respectively. I made the setup as simple as possible.

I now want to extract the different scalars from the vector f. I'm looking for:

```
>>> f.some_function_or_whatever(N.y)
2
```

Input is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For x, y, z coefficients set i to 0, 1, 2 respectively in the following line

f.to_matrix(N)[i]